# ASP.NET Core Web API Hangs When Adding Data to a Model Before Returning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

So I'm just cutting my teeth on ASP.NET Core MVC pages and Entity Framework all at once.
I have an SQLite database that has 2 tables in it.

The tables are configured like so:

Table 1 was created as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE collections (collections_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
datetime VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
seed INTEGER NOT NULL
```

Table 2 was created as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE samples (samples_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
datetime VARCHAR NOT NULL,
collections_id INTEGER NOT NULL, "
FOREIGN KEY(collections_id) REFERENCES collections(collections_id));
```

In my web API project, I created two models:

```
namespace FPSTestAPI.Models
{
    [Table("Collections")]
    public class CollectionModel
    {
        [Key, Column("Collections_id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Column("datetime")]
        public String Timestamp { get; set; }
        public long Seed { get; set; }        
        public List<SampleModel> Samples { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Samples")]
    public class SampleModel
    {
        [Key, Column("samples_id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Column("datetime")]
        public String TimeStamp { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CollectionModel"), Column("Collections_id")]
        public long Collection_Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So I then created a DB Context to read the information from the SQLite Database and wired this into an MVC web API I'm writing.

I created a Controller to retrieve data from the DB and it seems to be PARTIALLY working with the following code.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<CollectionModel>> Test()
{
    List<CollectionModel> collections = _context.CollectionModel.ToList(); // Line 1

    collections.ForEach(c => c.Samples = _context.SampleModel.Where(s => s.Collection_Id == c.Id).ToList()); // Line 2

    return collections; // Line 3
}
```

If I comment out the line designated Line 2 above, it works fine and returns a list of all Data_Collection elements.

However, if I uncomment the line designated Line 2 above the application seems to get hung somewhere and never returns. I have debugged the application and if I stop my execution on the return statement (Line 3) and examine the "collections" object then I can see that it is properly filled with the expected data. It just never returns.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be failing?

Comment: @GertArnold I have updated my code to use the actual code from my project. I think that you are correct that this is a circular reference as I was, at one point, getting that as an error. I thought I'd fixed it, but it's entirely likely it's still failing. I'm just not sure how to fix it in this case since my understanding of Entity Framework is quite minimal.

Comment: Hi @Briggs,I suggest you use efcore for migration to generate tables instead of creating tables yourself.It seems that there is a mismatch between the table you created and the class.

Comment: @yinqiu I'll give that a try. If still really like to figure out the cause of this particular issue however.

Answer (score 0):

You have navigation properties, which can be used for retrieving data in one roundtrip to database:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<CollectionModel>> Test()
{
    var collections = _context.CollectionModel
       .Include(m => m.Samples)
       .ToList(); 
    return collections;
}
```